Information about ruff rule when hovering above noqa in VS code
I just moved to a new laptop and apparently many settings weren't transferred despite it theoretically being sync'ed to my account.
On my previous system, whenever I would hover my mouse above a suppressed ruff rule, it would give me some minimal information about the ruff and have a link to the full explanation. This was very useful. On my new system nothing appears when hovering mouse.
I don't know if this is a vs code setting, a repo setting, or some other setting that is different. I so have all the same VS code extensions as before and the same packages installed in the env (although not 100% sure about the versions).
Any ideas how I can turn this on again?
